# Batch File add Extension to String

Tags: batch-file, string

I am new here and to batch scripting, trying to learn.

I have a batch that adds an extension to each string in a text file but what I have right now, it leaves a space before the extension.

```
@echo off 
set addtext=.mp4
for /f "delims=*" %%a in (list.txt) do (echo(%%a%%a%addtext%)>>new_list.txt
```

Any help is much Apppreciated!

To remove trailing white spaces I used a helper batch called [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044)
and this command in another batch file

```
call jrepl " +$" "" /f list.txt /o -
```

Thank You for the Help!

Comment: Have you ensured there's no trailing spaces on each line of the `list.txt` file?

Comment: How would I be able to verify that considering there is no extensions to determine the correct end of the string?

Comment: I believe there are spaces at the ends of the strings, when I click on a string, it's always 1 space too far.  How would you eleminate that space?

Comment: First, manually remove them from a test-variation of `list.txt`, and test.

Comment: That Worked!  Now I gotta do this for over 1000 strings...

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the `list.txt` files doesn't contain trailing whitespaces on the lines.

If it does, and if you want to have the batch file also trim trialing whitespace, check out this existing StackOverflow question:

- [Batch Remove Trailing Whitespace in a Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494509/batch-remove-trailing-whitespace-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your input file (no <>|&^) , this batch could do:

```
@Echo off
Type NUL >new_list.txt
for /F "delims=" %%a in (list.txt) do Call :Write %%a
Goto :Eof
:Write
>>new_list.txt Echo:%*
```

The `%*` will trim all leading and trailing spaces from the input.